# How to find lossy dimensions for large image

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would need a function, which takes two arguments width and height and return a new width and a new height which are reduced values below 100.

Examples:

1. w: 1920 h:1080 => returns w: 16 h: 9
2. w: 1921 h:1080 => returns w: 16 h: 9
3. w: 800 h:600 => returns w: 4 h: 3
4. w: 100 h:831 => returns w: 1 h: 8
5. w: 10 h:2000 => returns w: 1 h: 200
6. w: 2047 h:663 => returns w: 102 h: 33

For standardized screen resolutions, GCD is a great algorithm to find the greatest common divisor, but when I have non standard values like #2 example, it is not optimal for me.

Is there any algorithm, which could solve my algorithm problem? (The algorithm should be lossy, I know it is impossible without loss).

Here is my GCD algorith, which works for standard values:

```
function gcd($a, $b) {
    return ($a % $b) ? gcd($b, $a % $b) : $b;
}

function reduce(w, h) {
    var _gcd = gcd(w, h);
    return [w / _gcd, h / _gcd]
}

console.log(reduce(800, 600));
```

Comment: Does having a fixed set of ratios acceptable? You could quickly check which is the closest one.

Comment: Thanks @KarolyHorvath! No, it is not acceptable, I have added some more examples. The problem is that the user can upload any kind of image dimensions into the system. (The system will generate a placeholder image for HTML where width:100% applied. So if the user has a 1920*1080px image, it is enough to generate a 16*9px image and it will fill the same area in HTML and it speeds up the server for huge images.)

Comment: (+1) yes I agree with K.Horvath the ratios are integers up to 100 form OP definition so if space is not an issue create precomputed table of all combinations `1:99 .. 99:1` and then just use binary search on it and the aspect ratio to find closest match

Comment: @RolandSoós: to me, those examples don't make sense. For one of the images you create a ridiculously small 4x3 image while for the other a 102x33, just because it's slightly off from 3x1... it shouldn't matter, just crop the image.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have implemented your idea and posted as an answer. For 1921*1079 image it gives 73*41, which is great, but it could be more better to give 16*9. Do you see anything which I could optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on @KarolyHorvath and @spektre

The fraction is the object key which store the related dimensions.
Also the fraction added to an array, which array then sorted and binary search find the closest value to the fraction of reduce method. Then it returns the compressed dimensions.

```js
 function binaryIndexOf(searchElement) {
     'use strict';

     var minIndex = 0;
     var maxIndex = this.length - 1;
     var currentIndex;
     var currentElement;
     var resultIndex;

     while (minIndex <= maxIndex) {
         resultIndex = currentIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2 | 0;
         currentElement = this[currentIndex];

         if (currentElement < searchElement) {
             minIndex = currentIndex + 1;
         } else if (currentElement > searchElement) {
             maxIndex = currentIndex - 1;
         } else {
             return currentIndex;
         }
     }

     return~maxIndex;
 }

 Array.prototype.binaryIndexOf = binaryIndexOf;

 var helper = [],
     data = {};

 for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
     for (var j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
         var d = i / j;
         if (typeof data[d] == 'undefined') {
             data[d] = [i, j];
             helper.push(d);
         }
     }
 }

helper.sort(function (a, b) {
     return a - b
 });

 function reduce(w, h) {
     return data[helper[Math.abs(helper.binaryIndexOf(w / h))]];
 }

 console.log(reduce(1921, 1079));
```